# Is it OK to use a type hint on an existing variable?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I've got a module 'base.py':

```
class BaseA:
    @property
    def b(self):
        ''' returns a BaseB object '''
        ...

class BaseB:
    pass
```

And a child.py that imports from that module:

```
from base import BaseA, BaseB

class B(BaseB):
    pass

class A(BaseA):
    b: B
```

Because the exact return type of `A.b` is only defined in child.py, so I have put a type hint there without assigning any value. Is there any problem with doing this, such as somehow "overwriting" the variable?

This executes fine in Python 3.7 and PyCharm does not flag any error, but I just want to be sure because I have only seen it the other way around, the variable being assigned after the type declaration.